# Going from domestic flight to international flight at LAX

Tags: customs-and-immigration, international-travel, domestic-travel, lax

So I made a big mistake and decided to fly out of LA to Hong Kong. At the time I thought I had a ride down to the LA area, but unfortunately it fell through. Because of this I decided to book a flight out of San Francisco to catch my international flight in LA.

Thankfully I planned ahead and made sure I had at least 4 hour lay over in LA to find my international flight and to relax before the 21 hour flight to Hong Kong. Thankfully I am backpacking, so nothing is going to be in the bottom of the plane. The only thing I am worried about is do I need to go back through security and go through customs? or can I check-in on my phone? I do have an E-Ticket. I am going from Delta to Korean Airlines.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and revome all irrelevant information and opinions.

Comment: Do keep in mind that if your SFO-LAX flight is delayed by more than 2-3 hours, you may miss the LAX-HKG flight, and in this case the airline will probably cancel your reservation without refund.  You'll have to either buy a new ticket at the last minute (probably extremely expensive) or not go.

Answer (score 4):

Delta has airside shuttles connecting T2 to T3 and TBIT. (Only since Delta moved from T5/T6 to T2/T3 so some other sources might be outdated and not mention them.)

This [article](https://renespoints.boardingarea.com/2019/05/31/delta-lax-shuttle-bus-moves-gates-terminal-2-where-now-find-it/) however, is from May 31, 2019 and here it describes how to get from T2 to T3 / TBIT:

> After clearing security take a hard right. You’ll see gate 21 — which is an active gate boarding and deplaning flights. Keep venturing right and you’ll see the two shuttle bus queues: one for Terminal 3 (gates 30-39) and the other for TBIT. (Yes, the sign above says gates 130-150 and the one below 120-160…) Escalators or the elevator will take you down to the tarmac. From there, board the bus and grab a seat. The ride from T2 to T3 is about 3 minutes, door to door. It’s about 10 minutes from T2 to TBIT — and then a nice, long walk to the Delta gates.

Long walk -- this [blog post](https://onemileatatime.com/connect-terminals-lax/) mentions the TBIT drop off point is at gate 146, the end of the terminal.

This even more recent [flyertalk thread](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/delta-air-lines-skymiles/1974617-lax-shuttle-tbit-back-t2-t3.html) mentions it runs every 15 minutes or so. Also it mentions in T3 it is near gate 35 and points to this useful [map](https://www.delta.com/us/en/airports/united-states/los-angeles-sky-club-airport-map) on the website of Delta.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do mobile check in. There is no exit formality for the US. You will not have to do TSA again as T2 and TBT are connected airside via a bus and the ride takes approx 10 minutes depending on traffic. 4h should be MORE than plenty if your flight is somewhat on time. The linked site at the bottom gives a detailed description.

At T2 after security make a right and there's gate 21, you'll keep going right and see the bus lines. Take the one to Terminal B 1XX gates.

[Source](https://renespoints.boardingarea.com/2019/05/31/delta-lax-shuttle-bus-moves-gates-terminal-2-where-now-find-it/)

[image: T2 TO TBIT]

Comment: Thank you so much for the info! This is my first international trip, and I am hoping everything goes as planned. 